# How to rollover the standard output from bash?

Tags: bash, shell, logging, file-io, scripting

I have a script running in the background that prints some output. I redirected the standard output to a file for log purposes. However I don't want this file to grow forever, what would be a good way to do rollover without coding the logic myself? (Either rollover based on date or file size).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe the output into something like [multilog](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) it will handle all that stuff for you.

And example:

```
script_that_produces_output.sh |multilog s2000 ./logdir
```

will run the script capturing stdout to a file called `./logdir/current` rotating it when it is bigger than 2000 bytes.

Comment: Can you give a brief example on ho wto use multilog?

Answer (score 1):

[logrotate(8)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

Comment: This depends on the logging program to close and reopen the log after it is rotated.

Comment: `logrotate` can send a signal to the program which can trap and handle it. Easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

As well as multilog, there's also a similar tool called svlogd from the [runit](http://smarden.sunsite.dk/runit/) suite. You may find that already packaged in your distro, since daemontools (multilog) has only recently become public domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `rotatelogs` ([docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html)): all you need to do is pipe the output through it, provide few options and it will take care of the rest. For example:

```
your_script.sh | rotatelogs /var/log/your.log 100M
```

will automatically rotate the output file when it reaches 100M (can be configured to rotate based on a time interval).